# What is the code-behind equivalence of XAML <DataGrid Name="myDataGrid"/>?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind, equivalent

Can I add WPF items programmatically without any manual interference with XAML? Please give me a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

learning xaml markup is necessary step in wpf development, but yes, wpf app can be written purely in c#:

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataGrid myDataGrid;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var root = new Grid();

        myDataGrid = new DataGrid();
        var items = new ObservableCollection<DgItem> { new DgItem { Name = "A" } };
        myDataGrid.ItemsSource = items;

        root.Children.Add(myDataGrid);
        this.Content = root;
    }
}

public class DgItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: OK, Thanks! I'm a beginner in stackoverflow. 
But how to add properties automatically? Let's say you give a name "B", the "B" property should be added in DgItem class programmatically.

Comment: do you mean `(myDataGrid.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<DgItem>).Add(new DgItem { Name = "B" })`?

Comment: I'm very sorry for such a slow reply, the time difference is too big.
Yes, so long as to solve the problem. Your appending code works quite well !
Hotshot ! Very helpful ! Thanks a lot !